# Cloud Endpoints with Cloud SQL sample code

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I am looking to use Cloud Endpoints to create an API on the Google App Engine but all the tutorials I see are for how to interact with the Cloud Datastore. I am looking to use Cloud SQL though.

Does anyone have a Cloud Endpoints class sample code (in Java) that shows how to connect to Cloud SQL and execute some simple `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements? e.g.

```
INSERT message INTO messages
SELECT * FROM messages
```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late geeezzz guys

Comment: Cloud Endpoints essentially does the work of serialising/deserialising your Java objects and that's the same whatever database you use (if any), so the same tutorials apply for CloudSQL.

Comment: @tx802 So should I be asking then how to create a Java object that can write to Cloud SQL? So confused....

Comment: @tx802 maybe this is what i need? https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloudsql-jpatools

Comment: Yes, JPA will do the job if you're using CloudSQL. You can also read about using JPA with Cloud SQL [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Persistence_connectors)

Comment: Don't know why this is down voted, looks like a legible question to me. Will paste you some code later on

Comment: JDA and JDO have limitations, focused on the datastore. They are not able to do joins and other functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example Cloud Endpoint class that updates Cloud SQL. The example assumes the end point is authenticated

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.api.server.spi.ServiceException;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Named;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.ForbiddenException;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.InternalServerErrorException;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;

@Api(
    name = "myendpoint",
    version = "v1",
    clientIds = {"ddddd.apps.googleusercontent.com"},
    audiences = {"xxxx"}
)
public class CloudSqlEndpoint {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CloudSqlEndpoint.class.getName());

    private static final String INSERT_ORDER_SQL = "INSERT INTO order (amount, user, status, address) VALUES( ? , ? , ? , ? )"; 

/**
 * Insert a row into cloud sql
 * @param order
 * @param user
 * @return
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "order.add")
public Order addOrder(Order order, User user) throws OAuthRequestException, 
    IOException, ServiceException {

    this.validateUser(user);

    log.info("adding order to cloud sql: " + order);

    try {
         String url = null;
         if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
              SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
            // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            url = "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/guestbook?user=root";
        } else {
            // Local MySQL instance to use during development.
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root";

            // Alternatively, connect to a Google Cloud SQL instance using:
            // jdbc:mysql://ip-address-of-google-cloud-sql-instance:3306/guestbook?user=root
        }
        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_ORDER_SQL);
            stmt.setString(1, order.getAmount());
            stmt.setString(2, order.getUser());
            stmt.setString(3, "Open");
            stmt.setString(4, order.getAddress());

            stmt.executeUpdate();

        }

    } catch(Exception e) {

        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to create order", e);
        throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }

    return order;
}

/**
 * Validate the current user 
 * @param user
 */
private void validateUser(User user) throws OAuthRequestException, ServiceException {

    // validate the users domain
    if (user == null) {
        throw new OAuthRequestException("Invalid user.");

    } else {
        String email = user.getEmail().toLowerCase();

        // any other validation
    }

}

}
```

Comment: This is great. I am wondering where else I can find more samples?

Comment: Please also add a SELECT * omerio